# switching between scrollable tabs programmatically

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using scrollable tabs with `FragmentPagerAdapter` and I need to switch between the tabs programmatically

[image]

After clicking the create group button, I need to switch to the next tab i.e. manage group. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For just moving 1 step ahead you can do:

```
    int current = mPager.getCurrentItem();
    mPager.setCurrentItem(current + 1, true);
```

If you want to scroll to any specific index you can just pass that too:

```
    mPager.setCurrentItem(index, true);
```

You can also set smoothScroll flag as true/false which will give you smooth transition effect.

**EDIT:**

In your activity make a method :

```
public void scrollPager(int index) {
    if (mPager != null) {
        mPager.setCurrentItem(index, true);
    }
}
```

From your fragment when you hit the button you can either create a call back or simply call activity's method:

```
    ((ActivityName) getActivity()).scrollPager(1);
```

Comment: yes, but how to get the ViewPager Object from a fragment?

Comment: You will have to write a listener for this. On click of button it would trigger activity to run above code.

Comment: @DharanBro, i have edited my answer let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: ViewPager vp=(ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
    vp.setCurrentItem(2, true); it is working fine

Comment: @DharanBro do u mind marking this answer as correct if it helped you ?